# Ising model in 2d wrong heat capacity

Tags: python, c++, physics, scientific-computing

## The problem.

I'm trying to make a metropolis simulation of the 2D Ising model. My code reproduces some of the expected behaviour: i.e. there's a critical transition at vaguely the right temperature, but:

1. Energy has a smoothed-out transition. Magnetisation is a sharp step down from 1 to 0, while energy continues to rise, and doesn't show any change of gradient.
2. The heat capacity shows a peak, but instead of rising when I increase the lattice size, the peak gets smaller.
3. The heat capacity is noisy: the peak is often doubled, and fitting it to a Lorentzian is a nightmare. Worse yet, running the simulation multiple times gets me the same data (as evidenced by the small errorbar.

My project is a c++ program that simulates a single lattice, and a python script that analyses the output. As of now the script pipes the program stdout and assigns it to internal variables. It's inefficient, but that's for debugging purposes.

the full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/appetrosyan/Ising-Model-simulation.git). For convenience, see the main routines of the c++ program and the python script below.

## The code:

### lattice.h

...

```
/* Converts given pair of indices to those with periodic boundary conditions. */
int inline to_periodic(int row, int col, int size) {
  ...
}

class lattice {
private:
  unsigned int size_;
  std::vector<short> *spins_;
  float J_;
  float H_;

public:
  lattice() noexcept : size_(0), spins_(NULL), J_(1.0), H_(0.0) {}
  lattice(int new_size, double new_J, double new_H) noexcept
      : size_(new_size), spins_(new std::vector<short>(size_ * size_, 1)),
        J_(new_J), H_(new_H) {}
  lattice(const lattice &other) noexcept
      : lattice(other.size_, other.J_, other.H_) {
...
  float compute_point_energy(int row, int col);
};

#endif
```

### simulation.h

```
#ifndef simulation_h
#define simulation_h

#include "lattice.h"
#include "rng.h"
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>

class simulation {
private:
  unsigned int time_ = 0;  // Current time of the simulation.
  rng r_ = rng();
  lattice spin_lattice_;
  double temperature_;
  double mean_magnetisation_ = 1;
  double mean_energy_;
  double total_magnetisation_;
  double total_energy_;
  unsigned int print_interval_ = 1;
  void advance();

public:
  void set_print_interval(unsigned int new_print_interval) { print_interval_ = new_print_interval; }

  simulation(int new_size, double new_temp, double new_J, double new_H)
      : time_(0), spin_lattice_(lattice(new_size, new_J, new_H)), temperature_(new_temp),
        mean_energy_(new_J * (-4)), total_magnetisation_(new_size * new_size),
        total_energy_(compute_energy(spin_lattice_)) {}

  void print_status(FILE *f) {
    f = f==NULL? stdout : f;
    fprintf(f, "%4d\t%e \t%e\t%e\n", time_, mean_magnetisation_,
            mean_energy_, temperature_);
  }
  void advance(unsigned int time_steps, FILE *output);
  double compute_energy(lattice &other);
  double compute_dE(int row, int col) {
    return -2*spin_lattice_.compute_point_energy(row, col);
  }
  void set_to_chequerboard(int step);
  void print_lattice(){
    spin_lattice_.print();
  };
  // void load_custom(const lattice& custom);
};

#endif
```

### simulation.cpp

...

```
void simulation::advance(unsigned int time_steps, FILE *output) {
  unsigned int area = spin_lattice_.get_size() * spin_lattice_.get_size();
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < time_steps; i++) {    
    if (time_ % print_interval_ == 0) {
      total_magnetisation_ = spin_lattice_.total_magnetisation();
      mean_magnetisation_ = total_magnetisation_ / area;
      total_energy_ = compute_energy(spin_lattice_);
      mean_energy_ = total_energy_ / area;
      print_status(output);
    }
    advance();
  }
}

void simulation::advance() {
  // #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
  for (unsigned int row = 0; row < spin_lattice_.get_size(); row++) {
    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < spin_lattice_.get_size(); col++) {
      double dE = compute_dE(row, col);
      double p = r_.random_uniform();
      if (dE <0 || exp(-dE / temperature_) > p) {
        spin_lattice_.flip(row, col);
      }
    }
  }
  time_++;
}



double simulation::compute_energy(lattice &other) {
  double energy_sum = 0;
  unsigned int max = other.get_size();
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : energy_sum)
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
      energy_sum += other.compute_point_energy(i, j);
    }
  }
  return energy_sum/2;
}
```

### lattice.cpp

```
.....

void lattice::print() {
  ...
}

float lattice::compute_point_energy(int row, int col) {
  int accumulator = get(row + 1, col) + get(row - 1, col) + get(row, col - 1) +
                    get(row, col + 1);
  return -get(row, col) * (accumulator * J_ + H_);
}

int lattice::total_magnetisation() {
  ...
}
```

### investigator.py

```
.....
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------


def smart_duration(temperature, multiplier=1.):
    return int(((10**3)*base_duration*multiplier)/(
                (temperature - t_c)**2 + breadth))


def investigate_temperature_dependence(temps=None, lattice_sizes=None,
                                       **kwargs):
    if temps is None:
        temps = append(linspace(1.5, 2.2, 8), linspace(2.2, 2.3, 8))
        temps = append(temps, linspace(2.3, 4, 8))
    if lattice_sizes is None:
        lattice_sizes = [50, 250, 300]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex='col')
    ax[0].set_ylabel('mean magnetisation / arb. u.')
    ax[1].set_ylabel('mean energy / arb. u.')
    ax[0].axvline(x=t_c, color='k', ls='--')
    ax[1].axvline(x=t_c, color='k', ls='--')
    for l in lattice_sizes:
        print(l)
        simulations = [Simulation(lattice_size=l, temperature=t,
                                  duration=smart_duration(l, t)) for t in
                       temps]
        data = [multi_run(s, **kwargs) for s in simulations]
        terminal_magnetisations = array(data).T[0]
        sigma_magnetisations = array(data).T[1]
        terminal_energies = array(data).T[2]
        ax[0].plot(temps, terminal_magnetisations, '-',
                   label='N = ' + str(l))
        ax[1].plot(temps, terminal_energies, '-', label='N =' + str(l))
    plt.xlabel('temperature / arb. u.')
    plt.xticks(
        append(linspace(min(temps), t_c, 3), linspace(t_c, max(temps), 3)))
    save_plot('Critical temperature')


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------


def theoretical_capacity(x, a, b, c, d):
    return c + (b*x)/((x - a)**2 + d)


def investigate_heat_capacity(lattice_sizes=None, temps=None, **kwargs):
    if temps is None:
        temps = linspace(1.5, 3, 60)
    if lattice_sizes is None:
        lattice_sizes = [16,32, 34, 36]

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(lattice_sizes), sharex='col')
    crit_temps = []
    for l, ax in zip(lattice_sizes, axes):
        crit_temps.append(fit_and_plot_capacity(ax, l, temps, **kwargs))

    fig.set_size_inches(10.5, 10.5)
    plt.xlabel('temperature / arb. u.')
    save_plot('Heat capacity')
    return crit_temps


def fit_and_plot_capacity(ax, l, temps, **kwargs):
    """
    Plot the heat capacity of simulations at given temperature and lattice size.
    Afterwards fit a lorentzian and plot.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    ax : pyplot.axis
    what to plot to.

    l : int
    lattice size

    temps: numpy.array
    Array of temperatures where to evaluate heat capacity.

    Returns:
    -------
    popt[0]: float
    most likely critical temperature.
    """
    global use_disk
    use_disk = False
    simulations = [Simulation(lattice_size=l, temperature=t, duration=2)
                   for t in temps]
    # sigmas = [stdev(s.mean_energies[:]) for s in simulations]
    sigmas = array([multi_run(s, **kwargs) for s in simulations]).T[3]
    meta_sigmas = array([multi_run(s, **kwargs) for s in simulations]).T[4]
    # print(meta_sigmas)
    Cs = [sigma**2/(temp**2)*10**3 for temp, sigma in zip(temps, sigmas)]
    C_errs = Cs[:]*meta_sigmas[:]
    try:
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(theoretical_capacity, temps, Cs,
                               sigma=meta_sigmas, bounds=(
                [min(temps) - .2, 0, 0, 0],
                [max(temps) + .2, inf, inf, .7]))
    except RuntimeError:
        popt = [temps[argmax(Cs)], (max(Cs) - min(Cs))/4, min(Cs),
                (max(temps) - min(temps))/4]
        print('I\'m too dumb to fit')

    ax.axvline(x=popt[0], ls='--', color='g')
    ax.plot(temps, theoretical_capacity(temps, *popt), 'g-',
            label='N = ' + str(l) + 'd = ' + str(popt[3]) + ' fit')
    ax.errorbar(temps*10, Cs, fmt='b.', yerr=C_errs, label='N = ' + str(l))
    ax.set_ylabel(r'C $\cdot 10^3$/ arb. u.')
    ax.axvline(x=t_c, ls='-.', color='k')
    ax.set_xticks(
        append(linspace(min(temps), t_c, 6), linspace(t_c, max(temps), 6)))
    ax.legend(loc='best')
    return popt[0]


def multi_run(sim, re_runs:int=2, take_last:int=300):
    """
    Re run the Ising model simulation multiple times, and gather statistics.

    Parameters:
    ----------
    sim: simulation
    re_runs: int
    number of times to repeat simulation
    take_last: int
    How many of the final points to take statistics over.

    Returns:
    list:

    """
    global use_disk
    use_disk = False
    sim.duration = smart_duration(sim.temperature)
    print(sim.duration)
    magnetizations = []
    sigma_magnetizations = []
    energies = []
    sigma_energies = []
    for i in range(re_runs):
        sim.data = sim.run()
        # Make each run take 50% longer, so that we
        # can see if a system is still settling
        sim.duration *= 2

        last_magnetizations = sim.mean_magnetizations()[-take_last:]
        magnetizations.append(abs(mean(last_magnetizations)))
        sigma_magnetizations.append(std(last_magnetizations))

        last_energies = sim.mean_energies()[-take_last:]
        energies.append(mean(last_energies))
        sigma_energies.append(std(last_energies))

    return [mean(magnetizations), mean(sigma_magnetizations),
            mean(energies), mean(sigma_energies),
            std(sigma_energies)/mean(sigma_energies)]


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

def finite_size_scale(N, t_inf, a, v):
    return t_inf + a*(N**(-1/v))


def investigate_finite_size_scaling(critical_temperatures, lattice_sizes,
                                    **kwargs):
    if critical_temperatures is None:
        critical_temperatures = investigate_heat_capacity(lattice_sizes,
                                                          **kwargs)
    args, cov = curve_fit(finite_size_scale, lattice_sizes,
                                  critical_temperatures)
    plt.plot(lattice_sizes, critical_temperatures, 'b+', label='data')
    plt.plot(lattice_sizes, finite_size_scale(lattice_sizes, *args), 'r-',
             label='fit')
    plt.ylabel('critical temperature / arb. u.')
    plt.xlabel('Lattice size')
    save_plot('Finite size scaling')
    return args[0], sqrt(cov[0, 0])


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

t_c = 2/log(1 + sqrt(2))
use_disk = False
breadth = 1
base_duration = 50
sizes = [16, 32, 40, 50, 70]
# investigate_time_evolution()
# investigate_temperature_dependence(lattice_sizes=sizes, re_runs=4)

critical_temps = investigate_heat_capacity(lattice_sizes=sizes,
                                           take_last=300)

# temp_inf = investigate_finite_size_scaling(critical_temps, sizes)

#  print(temp_inf)
# print((t_c - temp_inf[0])/ temp_inf[1], ' Standard errors away')
```

## Pictures

To illustrate the problem take a look here:

[image: Plot of critical behaviout]

As I said, magnetisation is fine, but energy isn't. There isn't a sharp transition.

[image: Heat capacity]

Heat capacity is even worse. It starts to plateau for

## My thoughts.

I might simply not be running the simulation over a long enough time tens of thousands of MCS, and averaging over too few datapoints (the last 300), but then the errorbars would be bigger, or at least visible.

Comment: There is **way** too much code here. Please try to condense it down to a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also, please show some diagrams of the expected and actual results.

Comment: If you are convinced the problem is a programming problem and not a problem in modeling the physics, please try to boil it down to a MCVE. If the problem is in modeling the physics, you are probably better off asking on  Computational Science SE: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Computational Science SE https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I tentatively support @paisanco's proposal to ask it on scicomp SE, but I would suggest to *really* make sure that this is not an ordinary software bug, and also reduce amount of code, and maybe provide some plots (?). I for some reason have the vague feeling that the scicomp-people won't be happy with the wall of code either... You must subdivide the problem somehow, and build in more sanity checks at intermediate stages.

Comment: Ok, then I'll post it on scicomp.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I already Posted it on ghost town, ahem, Scicomp Stackexchange. I'm not sure this isn't a race condition, or indeed me implementing the metropolis algorithm the wrong way. MCVE is really a blade that cuts everyone: unless the project is really trivial, you get downvoted on wednesday for not including all the files, and then again, for including all of them on sunday. It passes the sanity checks, problem is, it's a monte-carlo simulation, just because it looks vaguely right, doesn't mean it is.  If I knew where the problem was, I wouldn't be asking a question here.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan Smaller sites of SE are often ghost-towns, sad but true... I think the main problem with this code is that everything is mixed together. You cannot find out whether your implementation of Metropolis is correct, because it is intertwined with the Ising model. There doesn't seem to be a way to test the Metropolis algorithm separately on simpler models. The Metropolis and the Ising model should be two separate entities, and they should be covered by separate unit tests. The chance that all components will work at once decreases exponentially with the number of components.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan Also, `FILE*`-output should be nowhere close to the steps of the simulation. Rather, the simulation should accept observers that can then write out stuff to file. Side-effecty things like `print_status(output)` are poison for testability.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I understand. I understand that it's difficult to answer in its current form. I trimmed it down, could you please make it so I CAN find help.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, I trimmed down the code as much as I could. Would you please, now let me find some help?

Comment: @paisanco, I understand, I've posted it on scicomp. I understand that you want to be strict, but could you please re-open this? I'm trying to debug this thing for a week, and scicomp seems to get roughly a percent of visitors stackoverflow does.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan As a 3K user I don't have the power to open (or for that matter close) questions by myself. I only get one close or open vote. Only a diamond moderator can open or close questions unilaterally. Otherwise you need 5 reopen votes from 3K users. I don't think your question is bad (and I don't think it deserves downvotes). But due to its complexity it may take some time to get an answer. I thought your odds would be better on Computational Science. There is less traffic but more of it could address your question.

Comment: I think you have the reopen votes now !